# How to copy from one canvas to another

Tags: android, user-interface, canvas

I want to copy the image drawn in one canvas ([details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)) into another canvas. The commonly discussed solution of using bitmaps will not work because the Bitmap class does not have many of the important methods belonging to the Canvas class. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Serialize all the draw commands and transfer those as an array to the other canvas, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Canvas is always used to draw either on screen or onto a Bitmap. The solution of using Bitmaps works perfectly well: create a Bitmap, create a Canvas to draw onto that Bitmap, then draw the Bitmap onto another Canvas. You also record all drawing commands in a Picture and replay them on a different Canvas.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that out soon and let you know how that works.

Comment: The reason for asking this question was to be able to maintain a Canvas without it getting erased every frame. The solution came from http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/505.html.

Comment: The above link is broken. A similar example is at http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html.