# Android: Drawing on a new canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I've created a custom view by extending View.

```
    public class CustomView extends View {
        private Canvas canvas2;
        private Bitmap backingBitmap;
```

In CustomView's constructor, I have the following code:

```
backingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas2 = new Canvas(backingBitmap);
```

In onDraw, I have:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
    canvas2.drawCircle(0, 0, 10, paint);
}
```

I can see the circle that gets drawn using "canvas" object, but not the one that's drawn using "canvas2" object.
My understanding is that one needs only create a mutable Bitmap and make it a Canvas' backing bitmap. Can someone point out what's wrong here?

Bonus question: Where does the custom canvas object get created on the screen, and how would one set its position?

Reason for creating multiple canvases: I have a SurfaceView which encompasses the entire screen. So, basically its canvas covers the entire screen. I need a make a window-like rectangle within the screen and stuff needs to animate within the bounds of that window. Basically, if you translate an image within this window, the image shouldn't get drawn outside the window's bounds.

Cheers!

Comment: why do you execpt the canvas2 content to be draw

Comment: Frankly, I was only half-expecting this to work. I thought there would be calls that would attach custom canvases to the Surface or something along those lines. I'm not able to find any more info in the documentation. Searching for solutions on the web hasn't yielded helpful results either. What's the correct process to create a new canvas?

Comment: Fst thing your custom `Canvas` object valid or not, definitely your `canvas2` won't render on your **surface** ever. When you create view it attached to window. At this point it has surface start drawing it gives you `canvas` ref provided by `onDraw()` method. So how can your surface know you have created another canvas object....think about this.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, that the Surface isn't aware of the canvas that I created. I'm trying to figure out how to make the Surface aware of this. And if that's not possible, what is the correct procedure for creating multiple canvases?
Edit: If multiple canvases cannot be created, how would one achieve what I've described in my "Reason for creating multiple canvases" section in the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my understanding. It all seems so simple now! This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852544/want-to-copy-from-one-canvas-to-another) helped.

Basically, when we create a Canvas object, it's creating an offscreen canvas that holds our drawing calls. This Canvas object needs to be backed by a mutable Bitmap, so that all the drawings finally get stored onto this Bitmap. Once the drawing is done, you can draw the mutable bitmap using the canvas that is tied to the surface (the canvas that you get in onDraw).

In my code, I made the following changes to get it working.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
    canvas2.drawCircle(25, 25, 25, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(backingBitmap, 200, 90, paint);
}
```

Comment: Great question and answer, was facing the same problem. +1 for both. Thanks!